# How to define map[string]object in yaml?

Tags: symfony, twig, yaml

How to define `map[string]` object in YAML?

I have JSON object

```
{
    "name": "SampleStore",
    "books": {
        "sample1": {
        "author": "test1",
        "prize": "1221"
       },
        "sample2": {
        "author": "test2",
        "prize": "890"
       }
    }
}
```

I had defined object in YAML as:

```
Types:
    store:
        name:
            type: String
        books:
            Items:
                Referemce: book_details
    book_details:
        author:
            type: String
        prize:
           type: String
```

But this is syntax for list, I want map of book. How to define these type of map in YAML?

Comment: There is no sequence (list) in your YAML. Please indicate what you think is a sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at this:

```
stores:
    -
      name: SampleStore
      books:
       -
        sample1:
         author: test1
         prize: 1221
       -
        sample2:
         author: test2
         prize: 1221
```

And you can try to run with this:

```
{%for store in stores %}
 {{ store.name }}

 {{ store.books|length }}
    {%for book  in store.books %}
          {{ book }}  
    {% endfor %} 

{% endfor %}
```

Will produce the output:

```
SampleStore

2
    Array  
    Array
```

You could play with it [at this link](https://twigfiddle.com/yi2z6l)

I would suggest you to use a key for the book title also in order to facilitate the access (something like `name: sample1`).

Hope this help